# Converting OpenCV kinect_maps to DLL

Tags: c++, dll, opencv, kinect

I'm new to making DLL's and I would like to convert the C++ kinect_maps project which i got from the OpenCV2.3 project examples to a DLL so i can use it from my C# project. I've been able to create a DLL but without luck it can't grab images from my kinect. Is it my linking to the libraries that is wrong or any other stuff I dont know. Any solutions on how can I accomplish my task?

Thank you so much! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: attach a debugger to your working exe, and attach a debugger to your broken C#. make sure to enable debugging native code.  tell us how they differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a COM interface because they are different languages. Find a COM/COM+ tutorial, try it at first with some simple "Hello world" (COM is not the simplest technology in the world), and then put your code in the COM dll.

Then you''ll be able to add it as reference to your C# project, #import it, instantiate classes, call member objects, and all the rest.